# How can we maintain the insertion order in SmartGwt ListGrid

Tags: smartgwt

There are some elements in my ListGrid which are coming from the DataSource.At client side I am adding some elements in it from multiple drop downs.I was able to save it Also.

In that Listgrid after adding some elements i am rearranging the elements by setting the ListGrid Property setCanReorderRecords(true).

In this change Order i have to save and fetch the Listgrid Record.

Example-

Combobox1   Combox2   ADD_button

id     name   value

1       aa     22

2       bb     33

On add button click I have added Selected  elements from Combobox in the Listgrid.and change the sequence like....

id name value

5  DK     99

2  bb     33

1  aa     22

In the same order i have to save & fetch the data from the dataSource.

Comment: could u specify your question little more clear ?

Comment: @Ankit :I have explained it with example i think now u get the Clear Picture.....

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the *sort order* in the database. After a fetch you just need to sort the ListGrid by the *sort order* field.
Now you need to register a drop handler to adjust all the *sort order* fields of the records involved in the resorting process.
Addditionaly I would recomment to register a sortChangeHandler so, that reordering is only enabled when the ListGrid is sorted by the *sort order* field.